# How to pass string arguments to a function using QT and C++

Tags: qt

When I call getCount function in the below code, QT 4.7.3 complier giving the error. Build Error

pasing 'cont Person' as 'this' argument of 'int Person::getCount(const QString&) discards qualifiers

```
 bool Person::IsEligible(const QString& name)
 {
      int count = 0;
      count = getCount(name);
 }

 int Person::getCount(const QString& name)
 {
  int k =0
  return k;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't a problem with passing string arguments, it's that you've got a `const` person, e.g.:

```
const Person p1;
Person p2;
p1.IsEligible("whatever"); //Error   
p2.IsEligible("whatever"); //Fine because p2 isn't const
```

If `IsEligible` is meant to be callable on `const Person`s then you can say:

```
bool Person::IsEligible(const QString& name) const
 {
      int count = 0;
      count = getCount(name);
 }
```

(and change the corresponding declaration that you've not shown too obviously), but I'm not 100% sure that's what you intended to do.

Comment: Thanks awoodland, delcarations are int getCount(const QString& name). bool IsEligible(const QString& name) const which is a public slots. I will change as you mentioned.